# Изменение Background у окна при нажатии на кнопку WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf

Нужно, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку изменялся цвет окна. Как это сделать? Программно. Через С#

Comment: Mvvm юзаете, или по старинке прям из кода хотите?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xaml
<Button Content="Click me!" Click="Button_Click"/>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```csharp
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
}
```